# How do I set up a Foreign Key

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, android-room

What I have setup are two tables, one for a user created account, and the other that lets the user buy a product.

I have both tables set up like so

**Customer Table**

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int custId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "country")
    private String country;
```

**Phone Table**

```
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int productId;
    private String phoneMake;
    private String phoneModel;
    private String phoneColor;
    private String storageCapacity;
    private Float  price;
```

What I have set up are two foreign keys, one in each table. My last table is for ordering the phones, which requires using both Primary Keys from each table. What I feel like I need is a ForeignKey, similar in vein to the PrimaryKey already created. The problem is that I am unsure how to implement that into the program. Everything I try doing is not working. I have looked at the documentation, but nothing clicks. I hope you can help me with the correct screenshot. If more is needed let me know (This code is written in Java code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want a Customer to have 1 phone, then you have have a single column (member variable) for the relationship that will store the phone's product id.

e.g.

```
private int mapToPhone; //<<<<< ADDED no need for @ColumnInfo the column name will be as per the variable name.
```

Obviously you set the value to an appropriate value.

To then get the Customer with the phone's details then you have a POJO that embeds the parent (Customer) using the `@Embedded` annotation has the child (Phone) using the `@Relation` annotation.

e.g. :-

```
class CustomerWithPhoneDetails {
   @Embedded
   Customer customer;
   @Relation(
           entity = Phone.class,
           parentColumn = "mapToPhone",
           entityColumn = "productId"
   )
   Phone phoneDetails;
}
```

You can then have a method in the @Dao annotated interface/abstract class which queries the parent table BUT returns the POJO or list/array of the POJO e.g. :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Customer")
abstract List<CustomerWithPhoneDetails> getAllCustomersWithPhoneDeytails();
```

**Example**

Based upon your code, and the additional example code along with an `@Database` annotated abstract class :-

```
@Database(entities = {Customer.class,Phone.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance = null;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and an Activity e.g. :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        long phone01ProductId = dao.insert(new Phone("PhoneMaker001","Model001","Color001","100Mb",111.11F));
        long phone02ProductId = dao.insert(new Phone("PhoneMaker002","Model002","Color002","200Mb",222.22F));

        dao.insert(new Customer("c001","password001","firstname001","lastname001","address001","city001","country001","postcode001",(int) phone01ProductId));
        dao.insert(new Customer("c002","password002","firstname002","lastname002","address002","city002","country002","postcode002",(int) phone02ProductId));

        for(CustomerWithPhoneDetails cwpd: dao.getAllCustomersWithPhoneDeytails()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Customer is " + cwpd.customer.getUserName() + " etc.  Phone is " + cwpd.phoneDetails.getProductId() + " etc." );
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that suitable constructors have been coded in both the Phone and Customer class *(default/empty constructor and one, annotated with `@Ignore` annotation that allows all values bar the id to be passed as used in the example below)*
- Note that ideally long rather than int should be used for the id columns.

**Results**

**The Log** :-

```
D/DBINFO: Customer is c001 etc.  Phone is 1 etc.
D/DBINFO: Customer is c002 etc.  Phone is 2 etc.
```

**App Inspection** :-

[image]

and :-

[image]